# Is it possible to achieve Stripe-style API version pinning using the Connexion library?

Tags: python, rest, flask, openapi, connexion

We use the Connexion python library to create our RESTful flask python API. (i.e., we have an OpenAPI schema defined and we load it into connexion and that defines the routes and helps perform validation and so forth.)

We would like to implement version-pinning in the same vein as Stripe—[see the blog post](https://stripe.com/blog/api-versioning).

Does Connexion have functionality to support Version Pinning? The only reference at all to versioning I see in [the docs is a passing reference](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/routing.html#api-versioning-and-basepath) that with routing you can setup a base path like `/v1` to prefix your URLs.